# How do I compare the the text of a UITextField to a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a scrambled word game that consists of 4 words, and therefore 4 textfields.

When the user inputs a string that is the length of the correct word, I want to check if that sequence is equal to the actual word.

```
 If it is, I want to clear the text field and return "YES!".

 If it is not, I want to clear the text field completely so the user can try again.
```

Example: If the actual word is "LOGIC" and the user enters "GOLIC" as his guess for the correct word, I want the text field to clear completely so the user can try again.

```
     If the actual word is "LOGIC" and the user enters "LOGIC", I want the text field to clear and display the string "YES!"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

UITextField has a property "text", which you should use. To compare to NSStrings you use isEqualToString method.

```
if([myTextField.text isEqualToString:actualWord]) {
    //display YES!
}
myTextField.text = @"";
```

Btw. you can use an UIAlertView to display YES if you want:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YES!" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Tie this to the editingDidEnd action of the textField.

```
- (IBAction)testText:(id)sender
{
    if ([myTextField.text isEqualToString:@"Logic"]) {
        myTextField.text = @"Yes";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YES!" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
        myTextField.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file (depending on what access permissions you want to have over that property) of the view to which the UITextField belongs you should add:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
```

inside:

```
@interface SettingsViewController ()

//Other code

@end
```

You can also connect the UITextField as an Outlet from the Storyboard:

1. Press the Suit in the top left corner of Xcode
2. Select from one side the Storyboard and from the other side the Class where you want to access the Outlet (the property) from.
3. Press the control button and drag from the UITextField to the interface block in that class.

Here is a link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=xq-a7e_l_4I#t=120s

Then in your code you can access it with:

```
[self usernameField].text
```

And you can check it with:

```
if ([[self usernameField].text isEqualToString @"YOUR STRING"]) {
//Code
} else {
//Code
}
```